# SQL Query to find single letters in a string

Tags: sql, database

I need a SQL query that will select all of the single letters in a string eg:

> I am a string..
>
> I am another string..
>
> I am the third and fina l string..

So this would find the first and last rows because they contain a single letter surrounded by spaces.

Comment: So you *specifically* don't want to match single letter words if they are the first or last word in the string, and there are no punctuation issues to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `_` wildcard, which means any one character:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   col1 like '% _ %'
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't know why i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    <TABLE>
WHERE   ' '+<COL>+' ' LIKE '% _ %'
```

Here in the where clause, I am adding a space at both ends so that, It will take single letter in the begining and end of the string as well